# How to add validation to a spring boot java form

Tags: java, forms, validation, spring-boot

I currently have the following method within my controller that takes the users form input and passes it to an SQL query to return a list of matches.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resultsPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newSearch(HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    List<newobject> listSearch = newDAO.loadSearch(id);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("results");
    model.addObject("listSearch", listSearch);
    return model;
}
```

I have added @NotNull to the ID filed in the newObject however I am unsure on how to modify my method above to check the variable entered (or not entered) by the user.

I am also unsure how to display the error on the html page. My existing code is below:

```
 <form method="get" th:action="@{/results}">
        <input id="search" name="id"  class="search" placeholder="Ref..." 
        type="text" maxlength="10" title="Numerical values only" />

        <button type="submit" method="post" style="display:none;" id="search">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how I would add the validation as I am just getting errors with everything I try.

Comment: To start with, you're throwing away most of the value of Spring by doing everything manually. Don't pass in the request and look up the ID, write the method as `newSearch(@RequestParameter Integer id)`.